# How do I convert a PHP SOAP script to work in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, soap

I've been trying (unsuccessfully) to work out how to write the following PHP code, as JavaScript:

```
<?php
$api_key = "abc1234567890"; 
$loc="https://soap.somedomain.co.uk/edi/soapsr.pl";
$uri="https://soap.somedomain.co.uk/StockQuery"; # package
$client = new SoapClient(null, array('location' => $loc,
                                     'uri'      => $uri,
                                     'compression' => "SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP | 5"
                                     ));

$stock_ids=array(1,6,15,16,167,169,170,171,172,173,175,176,5177,5178,5179,5180,5181);
$StkQtys = $client->stock_qty_array($api_key,$stock_ids);
echo var_dump($StkQtys); 
unset($client);
exit;
?>
```

I found a jquery.soap plugin, that sounds promising, but because of my lack of understanding, I'm struggling to work out how to use the parameters above in the correct way.

I'm not sure where I should put the '$loc' and '$uri' when using $.soap()
Also, how should I structure the data: {} object to include the required information?
I've tried the following, but no luck:

```
<script>
function soap() {
  $.soap({
        loc: 'https://soap.somedomain.co.uk/edi/soapsr.pl',
    url: 'https://soap.somedomain.co.uk/StockQuery',
        compression: 'SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP | 5'
    data: {
        stock_qty_array: { 'myAPIKey', {1,6,15,16,167,169,170,171,172,173,175,176,5177,5178,5179,5180,5181} }
    },
    success: function (soapResponse) {
                console.dir(soapResponse);
    },
    error: function (SOAPResponse) {
                console.dir(SOAPResponse);
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

When I run my code, I get the error:
`POST https://soap.somedomain.co.uk/StockQuery net::ERR_FAILED`

Any advice would be greatly appreciated?

Thank you, Chris

Comment: In your PHP, I see you have an Array like: `[ $api_key, $stock_ids]`, yet in your JavaScript, you have an Object defined with the parameter `myAPIKey`, and then an Object of your Stock IDs. This is likely where the issue lies. I think you want your Stock IDs to be in an Array not an Object.

Comment: Thank you Twisty, I'll retry with your suggestion